# Errno 22 when using shutil.copyfile on dictionary values in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am getting a feedback error message that I can't seem to resolve. I have a csv file that I am trying to read and generate pdf files based on the county they fall in. If there is only one map in that county then I do not need to append the files (code TBD once this hurdle is resolved as I am sure I will run into the same issue with the code when using pyPDF2) and want to simply copy the map to a new directory with a new name. The shutil.copyfile does not seem to recognize the path as valid for County3 which meets the condition to execute this command.

Map.csv file

```
County  Maps
County1 C:\maps\map1.pdf
County1 C:\maps\map2.pdf
County2 C:\maps\map1.pdf
County2 C:\maps\map3.pdf
County3 C:\maps\map3.pdf
County4 C:\maps\map2.pdf
County4 C:\maps\map3.pdf
County4 C:\maps\map4.pdf
```

My code:

```
import csv, os
import shutil
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

merged_file = PdfFileMerger()
counties = {}
with open(r'C:\maps\Maps.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for n, row in enumerate(reader):
        if not n:
            continue
        county, location = row
        if county not in counties:
            counties[county] = list()
        counties[county].append((location))
    for k, v in counties.items():
        newPdfFile = ('C:\maps\Maps\JoinedMaps\County-' + k +'.pdf')
        if len(str(v).split(',')) > 1:
            print newPdfFile
        else:
            shutil.copyfile(str(v),newPdfFile)
            print 'v: ' + str(v)
```

Feedback message:

```
C:\maps\Maps\JoinedMaps\County-County4.pdf
C:\maps\Maps\JoinedMaps\County-County1.pdf
v: ['C:\\maps\\map3.pdf']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 22, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: "['C:\\\\maps\\\\map3.pdf']"
```

There are no blank lines in the csv file. In the csv file I tried changing the back slashes to forward slashes, double slashes, etc. I still get the error message. Is it because data is returned in brackets? If so, how do I strip these?

Comment: `"['C:\\\\maps\\\\map3.pdf']"` is not a valid filename.  It's a string version of a list containing a single filename.

Comment: Ok. How do I rewrite code to compensate for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to create the file `['C:\maps\map3.pdf']`, you can tell this because the error messages shows the filename its trying to create:

`IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: "['C:\\\\maps\\\\map3.pdf']"`

This value comes from the fact that you are converting to string, the value of the dictionary key, which is a list here:

```
shutil.copyfile(str(v),newPdfFile)
```

What you need to do is check if the list has more than one member or not, then step through each member of the list (the `v`) and copy the file.

```
for k, v in counties.items():
    newPdfFile = (r'C:\maps\Maps\JoinedMaps\County-' + k +'.pdf')
    if len(v) > 1:
        print newPdfFile
    else:
        for filename in v:
            shutil.copyfile(filename, newPdfFile)
            print('v: {}'.format(filename))
```

Comment: Awesome. I take it I apply the same method when appending the files to a new pdf when list is greater than 1?

Comment: Yup, just replace the `shutil.copyfile` part with whatever logic combines PDFs.